# Show that $O\backslash E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\backslash E_i.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $O=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ and $E_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i$. How can I show that $$O\backslash E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\backslash E_i.$$

I have that $$O\backslash E=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\Big\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\cap \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i^c.$$

I would say that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \subset E_i^c$ and thus $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\cap\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty E_i^c\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\cap E_i^c=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\backslash E_i$$

but I'm not totally sure about my argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in O$ means $\exists i$ such that $x \in O_i$. $x \notin E$ means $\forall j$, $x \notin E_j$. Thus, $x \in O - E = O \cap E^C$ means, in the above notation, $x \in O_i - E_i \subseteq \bigcup O_j - E_j$.

Your argument of manipulating the sets directly seems fine to me as well.